# Validate presence on after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy  
  after_create :build_profile
end
```

So when the user registers, there profile is created and they are redirected to the `edit_profile_page`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_profile_path(current_user)
  end

end
```

In my profile model I'm trying to set some validation

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Im also using the friendly_id gem

profile_controller.rb

```
def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

The error I'm getting is when I register a new user is:

```
Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=6
```

This only happens when I try to apply the `validates :name, presence: true`, without this my application works fine. I need a way to validate the name after the user is registered, after the profile model is created.

Im also getting the error at this line:

```
def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: try redirecting with `edit_profile_path(current_user.profile.id)` and see what happens.

Comment: Tried the above, getting this error `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build_profile` in `after_create` builds a profile but it doesn't persist it.  It's not created in the database.

Better might be...

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_profile_path
  end
```

In your controller

```
def new
  @profile = current_user.build_profile
  ...
end

def create
  @profile = current_user.build_profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```